# Fastest way to create this matrix in R

Tags: r

I have two vectors `r` and `s`. I want to find the outer difference of these two arrays and not be negative like the following

```
r = rnorm(100000)
s = c(0.02, 0.04, 0.3, 0.43, 0.5, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9)
res = t(pmax(outer(r, s, "-"), 0))
system.time({
res = t(pmax(outer(r, s, "-"), 0))
})
## system elapsed 
## 0.05    0.00    0.05
```

or

```
system.time({
    x = pmax(r - rep(s, each = length(r)), 0)
    res = matrix(x, nrow = length(s), byrow = TRUE)
})

## system elapsed 
## 0.05    0.00    0.05
```

How can I get faster the result x in R?

Comment: Maybe you could describe what you're trying to do in words

Comment: You could probably dig around in the internals of `outer` and just pull out the bits that actually do the calculations with no checking. Not sure if it would really be worth the fractions of seconds you'd save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @thelatemail's comment:

```
fun1 <- function(r,s) t(pmax(outer(r, s, "-"), 0))


fun2 <- function(r,s) {
  x = pmax(r - rep(s, each = length(r)), 0)
  matrix(x, nrow = length(s), byrow = TRUE)
}

fun3 <- function(r,s) {
  dr <- length(r)
  ds <- length(s)
  R <- rep(s, rep.int(length(r), length(s)))
  S <- rep(r, times = ceiling(length(s)/length(r)))
  res <- pmax(S - R, 0)
  dim(res) <- c(dr, ds)
  t(res)
}

library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(res1 <- fun1(r,s),
               res2 <- fun2(r,s),
               res3 <- fun3(r,s),
               times=20)

# Unit: milliseconds
#               expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
# res1 <- fun1(r, s) 43.28387 46.68182 66.03417 78.78109 83.75569    20
# res2 <- fun2(r, s) 50.52941 54.36576 56.77067 60.87218 91.14043    20
# res3 <- fun3(r, s) 34.18374 35.37835 37.97405 40.10642 70.78626    20

identical(res1, res3)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: The Rcpp solution (wrapped into an R function call that returns a result) seems to be 3 times faster than `fun3`.

Answer (score 2):

I get slightly faster performance by running the `outer` function seperately and the subsetting zero `< 0` entries like this...

```
res1 <- t( outer( r , s , "-" ) )
res1[ res1 < 0 ] <- 0
```

But if you want even more speed then try using `Rcpp`. It's easy enough, just run the following code snippet....

```
if( ! require( Rcpp ) ) install.packages( "Rcpp" )
Rcpp::cppFunction( '
    NumericMatrix gtzero(NumericVector r , NumericVector s){
        int cols = r.size();
        int rows = s.size();
        NumericMatrix out(rows, cols);
        for( int i = 0; i < cols; i++){
            NumericMatrix::Column ncol = out( _, i );
            ncol = ifelse( r[i] - s > 0 , r[i] - s , 0 );
        }
        return out;
    }
    ')
```

Then use the function like this:

```
gtzero( r , s )
```

This turns out to be about 6 times faster than using `outer` and `pmax` and 3 times faster than `outer` then `[` subsetting:

```
require( microbenchmark )
bm <- microbenchmark( eval( rose.baseR ) , eval( simon.baseR ) , eval( simon.Rcpp ) )

print( bm , "relative" , order = "median" , digits = 2 )
#Unit: relative
#              expr min  lq median  uq max neval
#  eval(simon.Rcpp)   1 1.0    1.0 1.0 1.0   100
# eval(simon.baseR)   3 3.1    3.2 3.2 1.5   100
#  eval(rose.baseR)   3 3.4    6.0 5.9 1.8   100
```

And gives the exact same result:

```
identical( res0 , res2 )
#[1] TRUE
```

The following expressions were evaluated:

```
set.seed(123)
r = rnorm(100000)
s = c(0.02, 0.04, 0.3, 0.43, 0.5, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9)

rose.baseR <- quote({
    res0 <- t(pmax(outer(r, s, "-"), 0))
})

simon.baseR <- quote({
    res1 <- outer( r , s , "-" )
    res1[ res1 < 0 ] <- 0
})

simon.Rcpp <- quote({
    res2 <- gtzero(r,s)
})
```